# Multiple IDs in a single JavaScript click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, click

In JavaScript I am using click event to change chart data. Below is a method for click event.

```
$('#pro1').click(function () {
            chart.series[0].update({
                data: pro1
            });
        });
        $('#pro2').click(function () {
            chart.series[0].update({
                data: pro2
            });
        });
        $('#pro3').click(function () {
            chart.series[0].update({
                data: pro3
            });
        });
```

I need to minify these three click events in one event, means I want to write one click event which handle the id's. some thing like below code.

```
$('#pro'+i).click(function () {
chart.series[0].update({
     data: pro+i
});
});
```

I don't know how to do it exactly. The above code is not correct, it is just my lack of knowledge of JavaScript.

Comment: use a class and the magic "this" :)

Comment: it would be much easier if `pro` will be an array

Comment: yep use a class and the "i" woud be $(this).index();

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest creating an object and selecting the elements using classes, `id` of the clicked element retrieves value of the corresponding property of the helper object:

```
var pros = {
   pro1: '...',
   pro2: '...'
};

$('.pros').click(function () {
    chart.series[0].update({
        data: pros[this.id]
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense. `.pros` is a selector for a class called pros

Comment: @Liam Your comment does not make sense. I had suggested using classes. This is why there is a class selector there.

Answer (score 75):

Try this:

```
var that = this;
$('#pro1,#pro2,#pro3').click(function () {
    chart.series[0].update({
        data: that[$(this).attr('id')];
    });
});
```

Comment: in 2021, `var that = this;` should just be replaced with an arrow function

Answer (score 11):

```
$('#pro1,#pro2,#pro3').click(function () {
    chart.series[0].update({
        data: $(this).attr('id');
    });
});
```

Updated code

```
$('#pro1,#pro2,#pro3').click(function () {
    chart.series[0].update({
        data: window[this.id]
    });
});
```

Comment: `proN` is a variable not a string. If the variables are global `window[this.id]` will work.

Comment: do you really think that OP wants to pass string as chart data?

Answer (score 4):

Use a class.

```
$('.pro').click(function () {
 chart.series[0].update({
   data: $(this).attr('id');
 });
});
```

And then on each of the #pro1, #pro2, #pro3 elements add a class of 'pro'

Comment: You had `data: pro+i` without defining vars for `pro` or `i`. Downvote removed.

Comment: Cheers, was a work in progress. Was actually in the middle of it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("*[id^=pro]").click(function () {
    chart.series[0].update({
         data: $(this).attr('id');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give all of your elements a class name and use the :eq() selector within jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Using each function() you can do it

```
var i =0;
$("#pro"+i+", #pro"+i+", #pro"+i+"").each(function(){
            $(this).on('click', function(){
chart.series[0].update({
     data: pro+i
});

});});
```